# C# double formatting align on decimal sign

Tags: c#, formatting, double

I align numbers with various number of decimals so that the decimal sign aligns on a straight row. This can be achevied by padding with spaces, but I'm having trouble.

Lays say I want to align the following numbers:
0
0.0002
0.531
2.42
12.5
123.0
123172

This is the result I'm after:

```
     0
     0.0002
     0.531
     2.42
    12.5
   123.0
123172
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want exactly that result you can't use any formatting of numerical data, as that would not format `123` as `123.0`. You have to treat the values as strings to preserve the trailing zero.

This gives you exactly the result that you asked for:

```
string[] numbers = { "0", "0.0002", "0.531", "2.42", "12.5", "123.0", "123172" };

foreach (string number in numbers) 
{
    int pos = number.IndexOf('.');
    if (pos == -1) 
        pos = number.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', 6 - pos) + number);
}
```

Output:

```
     0
     0.0002
     0.531
     2.42
    12.5
   123.0
123172
```

Comment: This could be improved by respecting the culture-specific decimal separator.

Comment: @ClickRick: Yes, but then you need to specify what culture was used to produce the strings. The strings are not treated as numbers anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 1):

### General Example

```
string.Format("{0,7:##.00}", 2.356);  // "   2.36"
string.Format("{0,-7:##.00}", 2.356); // "2.36   "
string.Format("{0,7:00.00}", 2.356);  // "  02.36"
string.Format("{0,-7:00.00}", 2.356); // "02.36  "
```

See [Formatting Decimals in C#](https://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/) for complete details.

---

### Specific Answer

```
msg = string.Format( "{0,11:#####0     }\n"
                   + "{1,11:#####0.0000}\n"
                   + "{2,11:#####0.000 }\n"
                   + "{3,11:#####0.00  }\n"
                   + "{4,11:#####0.0   }\n"
                   + "{5,11:#####0.0   }\n"
                   + "{6,11:#####0     }\n"
                   ,      0
                   ,      0.0002
                   ,      0.531
                   ,      2.42
                   ,     12.5
                   ,    123.0
                   , 123172
                   );
Console.WriteLine(msg);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: there is no general purpose format string for all example data... if you want a general purpose routine use Guffa's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly answering the question because of the trailing zeros, this aligns decimal points with 4 decimal places and a maximum of 11 characters in total.

```
someNumber.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
```

Eg. the following strings

```
0d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
0.0002d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
0.531d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
2.42d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
12.5d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
123.0d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
123172d.ToString("0.0000").PadLeft(11)
```

are

```
     0.0000
     0.0002
     0.5310
     2.4200
    12.5000
   123.0000
123172.0000
```

in the invariant culture.

Answer (score -2):

You can use string.format or ToString method of double to do so.

```
double MyPos = 19.95, MyNeg = -19.95, MyZero = 0.0;

string MyString = MyPos.ToString("$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero");

// In the U.S. English culture, MyString has the value: $19.95.

MyString = MyNeg.ToString("$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero");

// In the U.S. English culture, MyString has the value: ($19.95).
// The minus sign is omitted by default.

MyString = MyZero.ToString("$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero");

// In the U.S. English culture, MyString has the value: Zero.
```

[this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28VS.71%29.aspx) from msdn can help you if you need more details