# Floating Point fixed length Number formatting c#

Tags: c#, string-formatting, format-specifiers

I want to format a floating point number as follows in C# such that the entire width of the floating point number in C# is a fixed length (python equivalent format specifier 6.2f) I do NOT want it to be padded with 0's on the left but padded with a white space

```
100.00
 90.45
  7.23
  0.00
```

what I have tried so far

```
string.Format({0:###.##},100); 
string.Format({0:###.##},90.45);
string.Format({0:###.##},7.23);
string.Format({0:###.##},0.00);
```

but the output is incorrect

```
100
90.45
7.23
      //nothing is printed
```

I have also gone through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString) but am unable to find a solution.
I am aware of the string.PadLeft method, but I am wondering if there is a more proper way than

```
(string.format({0,0.00},number)).PadLeft(6," ")
```

**EDIT**
I am specifically asking if there is a correct inbuilt method for the same, not if it can be done with same mathematical wizardry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# double formatting align on decimal sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332912/c-sharp-double-formatting-align-on-decimal-sign)

Comment: @maccettura how is this a duplicate? I have asked if there is a format specifier to do this? Now if it can be dont? anyone can write a complicated set of if statements to achieve my goal, I asked if there is a inbuilt c# method

Comment: I don't know of a format string that will do this, but your left-pad looks fine to me...

Comment: @SiddharthChabra how do you expect a format specifier would know about the length of all your other numbers?  You are looking for your numbers to align, the duplicate addresses this perfectly.  If you want to know if a format specifier could do it, then the answer is **no**

Comment: @maccettura have you ever tried `string.format({0,16},integer)` this tells C# to assign a 16 digit space for the integer even if the number is smaller and expands of the number is larger. Please remove your duplicate Tag as the post Tagged does Not answer my question

Comment: @SiddharthChabra specifying the padding isnt the hard part.  Knowing where the decimal place is ahead of time, when each individual number can be formatted/rounded/truncated is the hard part.

Comment: @maccettura I think you should read the link I have tagged since I am "specifying"  `.00` i am clearly indicating decimal places = 2 if not 2 add 0's and make it 2. You do know this can be done in c/c++/python without issue, So I asked if it can be done in C#, If the answer is No so be it but let the community answer, Incorrectly tagging is as duplicate is not acceptable

Comment: @SiddharthChabra I actually think I might have found an answer.  I didn't think this function was supported in the way you wanted but the solution I found might work.  It pads with zeros though.

Comment: @maccettura Please look at the answer below. it can be done using a format specifier without padding 0's .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want 2 digits after the decimal, you can specify 00 in the format specifier. You would need to use a right aligned field width also (I used 6 as the max field width).

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6:##0.00}",100.0)); 
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6:##0.00}",90.45));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6:##0.00}",7.23));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6:##0.00}",0.00));
}
```

In LinqPad it outputs:

```
100.00
 90.45
  7.23
  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

In **.NET 5.0+** you don't need to call `string.Format` directly. Instead prefix your strings with `$` and delimit variables inside `{..}`

**Example**

```
double myfloat1 = 100.0;
double myfloat2 = 0.2;
Debug.WriteLine($"{myfloat1,8:0.00}");    //   100.00
Debug.WriteLine($"{myfloat2,8:0.00}");    //     0.20
```

The code `8:0.00` formats as fixed 8-length (space-padded) with 2 decimal places.